# What is the difference in meaning between these two statements?

Tags: verbs, ing

> Their powers should be limited to curbing INFLATION.

.........

> Their powers should be LIMITED to curb inflation.

I've written in uppercase the words emphasized by the speaker (in speech).

Comment: The former says that the only power they should wield is the power to curb inflation.  The latter says that in order to curb inflation, limits should be placed on their powers.  But that difference stems more from *curb* vs *curbing* than where the emphasis is placed.

Comment: Emphasis is a focusing device. The first sentence (I imagine that 'curbing' should also be stressed here) is focusing on the sensible amount of power 'they' should be given. The second sentence means that limiting 'their' powers is an important factor in bringing about a  decrease in the rate of inflation.

Comment: Is the difference between _curbing_ and _curb_ actually part of the question, or could this be a typing mistake by the OP? With the sentences as they stand, the difference in meaning between the two sentences is large enough to dismiss any stress the speaker puts on individual words as irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

They mean entirely different things:

> Their powers should be limited to curbing inflation.

means that it is desirable that they have no other powers than those which enable them to curb inflation.

> Their powers should be limited to curb inflation.

means that inflation may be curbed by limiting their powers and it is therefore desirable that their powers be limited.